It is possible to stop Blender gltf export process?
I am currently developing an add-on Blender that manages the export of some projects with conditions. These projects are hudge and I was wondering if there is a way to display an operator that would stop the export process when exporting. Exporting may take some time, for example 30 minutes or more.
I looked into api documentation, but i did not find something interessant.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
